# how to use header(first row) as field names in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Given a csv file with first row which can be taken as the header, how can one load the field names dynamically in Pig using these headers? i.e.

```
id,year,total
1,1999,190
2,1998,20

a = LOAD '/path/to/file.csv' USING PigStorage() AS --use first row as field names
> describe a;
> id:bytearray,year:bytearray,total:bytearray
```

Answer (score 2):

As this is a CSV file and you want to use first row as a header, you should use `CSVLoader()` for it.It will treat first row as header. Your script will be like this.

```
--Register the piggybank jar
REGISTER piggybank.jar
define CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();  

A = LOAD '/path/to/file.csv' using CSVLoader AS(id:int,year:chararray,total:int);
```

Comment: thanks but how can one load field names dynamically in Pig using these headers?

Comment: CSVLoader() always load first  row as headers. your load statement will be like this. A = LOAD '/path/to/file.csv' using CSVLoader(); but ideally you should define datatype of the fields for further operations.

Comment: I mean field names as in pig schema. I'm not referring to skipping headers. I mean is it possible to load a csv file using a schema generated from headers?